# SQL Conversion Fail error from nvarchar to int

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  ITEMGROUPID ,
        ITEMID ,
        ITEMNAME ,
        ITEMTYPE ,
        COSTGROUPID ,
        SALESMODEL ,
        DIMENSION ,
        ( SELECT    DESCRIPTION
          FROM      DIMENSIONS
          WHERE     ( NUM = 0 )
                    AND ( DIMENSIONCODE = IT1.DIMENSION )
        ) AS Expr1
FROM    INVENTTABLE AS IT1
WHERE   ( DATAAREAID = 'm02' )
        AND ( ITEMGROUPID = 'FG' )
        AND ( ITEMID = '14901C' )
```

This query throws an error. The results should be that it takes the value (`int`) from column `IT1.DIMENSION` and searches the `Dimension` table and returns the value (`nvarchar`) from the description column within the `DIMENSIONS` table.

Upon execution it has the following error:

> Conversion Fail. When converting NVARCHAR value 'AG' to datatype INT.

The objective here is to eliminate the use of a left outer join between the two above tables `INVENTTABLE` and `DIMENSIONS`.

Comment: Soooo, you want to avoid a `LEFT JOIN`, but you want a correlated subquery instead?. On another note, what data type is `DIMENSIONCODE`?

Comment: Does the value 'AG' came from ITEMGROUPID column?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Since the only conversion that seems to take place can be in the "DIMENSIONCODE = IT1.DIMENSION" part in the correlated query my guess would be that you have a data type mismatch and that DIMENSIONCODE is defined as nvarchar. Of course it would be much easier to pinpoint the error if you had provided table definitions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you would do this by

> ...DIMENSIONCODE = Convert(int, IT1.DIMENSION)...

however that makes the generous presumption that the contents of the IT1.Dimension column is actually numeric.  If, in some circumstances, it does not contain something that can be translated to an Integer, then you would have to record as

> ...DIMENSIONCODE = Convert(int, iif(isnumeric(IT1.DIMENSION) = 1, IT1.DIMENSION, "1"))...

Where you are forcing a "1" into the result of the expression if IT1.DIMENSION isn't a valid numeric.  Since you aren't specific about which database you're using, you might have to use some variation.

Comment: THANK You for your most timely response. The convert would have work the way you envisioned it. However I've found a solution. The problem wasn't the conversion but rather it was my logic (human error). In my syntax I am comparing "DIMENSIONCODE to DIMENSION" and this will not work since DIMENSION should be paired with NUM. 
The code should have been 
WHERE     ( DIMENSIONCODE = 0 ) AND ( NUM = IT1.DIMENSION )

But none the less thank you for your response.
As it relates to the database details. It is a Microsoft AX2009 database.